# Call getBounds() on MapView.Circle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, expo

I want to call the getBounds(points) function from Geolib, on Map View.Circle component. I am not pretty sure, how do I fetch the list of coordinates inside my circle region. So that I can pass it as a parameter to the getBounds function.
I see posts where getBounds() from google maps API is being called on react google maps and so on. But not sure in this case.
Below is my code for map display and Circle. Please share your knowledge and suggestions.

```
<MapView style={styles.mapContainer} 
        region = {{latitude: region.latitude,
              longitude: region.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta}}
        >
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{
            latitude: region.latitude,
            longitude:region.longitude}}
            title={"Me"}
         />
         <MapView.Circle
                key = { (region.latitude + region.longitude).toString() }
                center = {pickedLocation}
                radius = { 100 }
                strokeWidth = { 2 }
                strokeColor = { '#1a66ff' }
                fillColor = { 'rgba(230,238,255,0.5)' }
        />
        </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably use geolib and do this

```
import { getBoundsOfDistance } from 'geolib';
const cordinates = getBoundsOfDistance({latitude: number, longitude: number}, radius);
mapRef.current?.fitToCoordinates(cordinates, {
                edgePadding: {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 20,
                },
            });
```